# How to create Virtual Machine in Azure Free Services without cost

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

Azure says [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/?ref=VSDevEssentials) that

> 750 Hours of B1S VM and 64 GB X 2 Managed Disks, 2 P6 SDDs

and some others are free each month for 12 months.

On VM create in Azure Portal, There are Basics, Disks and other tabs, In Basics, I could able to select Image Size to B1S VM but in Disks tab, there is no option to select Managed Disk of 64GB of P6 SDDs.

There are only three options i.e Premium SSD, Standard SSD, Standard HDD. Whatever I select and proceed further, VM takes default of 128 GB C Drive and 4 GB of Temp Drive and starts billing.

Where can I select that free 64 GB X 2 Managed Disks, 2 P6 SDDs.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can change disk os disk size at all (only increase it), but there are Windows images called `smalldisk`; those have 30gb disk. You can use those, they should work just fine.

[image]

Comment: How do I ensure that it is P6 SDD?

Comment: it will be less than p6, you cant edit disk size from the portal, as far as I remember, you can up scale it after

Comment: Ok, Let me try.

Answer (score 6):

Just hover mouse over "create" in the virtual machines tab in menu. That will show a "free VM" option. Click that and it configures everything required for a free VM.

Comment: it was a great tip really.. it is unbelievable that where they hide this option.. a pop-up appeared while I was on the vm option and then i scrolled to bottom and saw the option...

Answer (score 5):

In Azure Portal use the search square box (on top) and look for "Free Services" then you will be able to use free VM and other services.

Answer (score 1):

After making the VM, open the resource group of the vm. Click the disk of the vm (Be sure that the VM is to be switched off, else it won't work) and select the disk. Open the disk and on the sidebar click size and performance and resize the disk to p6.

Comment: Please limit your answer to be just an answer. If you have another question please use post a new question

Answer (score 0):

I think VM creation is not completely free. You have to pay for computing power and disk. Please response if I am wrong.